# htaccess - make and redirect .php to extensionless url with trailing slash

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I don't know much about mod rewrite and `.htaccess` but I am facing problem with my rules which I want but are not working as desired.

here is existing rules

```
# 1 ---- Establish a custom 404 File not Found page ----
ErrorDocument 404 /project/404.php
# 2 ---- Prevent directory file listing in all of your folders ----
IndexIgnore *

RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
Options -MultiViews
RewriteBase /project/

# pages.php page request
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /pages\.php\?page=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ pages/%1/? [R=302,L,NE]
RewriteRule ^pages/([^/]+)/$ pages.php?page=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

# from page.php to /page/
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$    $1.php    [NC,L] # rewrite rule to nice url look
```

1) all I want is dynamic rules without defining each rule for each file

for example I want simple pages like `page.php` to `/page/`

and this `page.php` could be any file name not necessary it is `page.php`

2) And I want if any url have GET vars like `page.php?var1=val1&var2=val2&var3=val3&...` etc to be changed into

`/page/val1/val2/val3/...` etc

and of course these vars and values also could be any named and value. (dynamically)

This rule is only for `pages.php` with var named `page` and only works with it, but not with single `page.php`

```
# pages.php page request
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /pages\.php\?page=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ pages/%1/? [R=302,L,NE]
RewriteRule ^pages/([^/]+)/$ pages.php?page=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

but I need `pages.php` to dynamically and also var `page` too, and  similarly unique rule for everything what I described above.

**summary of description**

1) need requests to redirect to extensionless urls

2) make `.php` to extensionles urls

3) and need everything to working with vars too

Comment: Keep one question per page please.

Comment: and how much questions am I asking?